# Already Answered Uncaught TypeError: state.concat is not a function error

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am following a tutorial for React and redux but at the end of the video I get an error even due I have the same code.

Uncaught TypeError: state.concat is not a function

Any help will be appreciate it!

```js
//action is a parameter and the reducer is the function
//We will make change to the state based on the action (function)

//Function will be reducers
const cards = (state, action) => {
    switch (action.type){
        case 'ADD_CARD':
            let newCard = Object.assign({}, action.data, {
                score: 1,
                id: +new Date
            });
//error is here
            return state.concat([newCard]);
        default:
            return state || {};
    }


};

//Redux helper function to pass reducer functions
const store = Redux.createStore(Redux.combineReducers({
    cards: cards
}));

//Keep an eye on the store for changes
store.subscribe(() => {
    console.log(store.getState());
});

//activate store action
store.dispatch({
    type: 'ADD_CARD',
    data: {
        front: 'front',
        back: 'back'
    }
});

//Another action
store.dispatch({
    type: 'ADD_CARD',
    data: {}
});
```

Answer (score 2):

State should be an object, not an array, so .concat will not work on it. You will have to do something like state.cards.concat(foobar). Correct me if I'm wrong here, but take a look at state and verify its type.

Comment: In this case state is a property of cards and it is an array according to the author in the video ? Thanks

Comment: can you check it in debugger and confirm that? or just console log it and send me the output.

Comment: Could you share the tutorial you're talking about and the complete code?

Comment: UPDATED I just fixed the problem by returning state || [ ]; instead of { }

Comment: I don't know how to mark it answer ?? @steveacerda7

Answer (score 0):

I was returning an object { } instead of an array [ ] at the default level in cards.

```js
//action is a parameter and the reducer is the function
//We will make change to the state based on the action (function)

//Function will be reducers
const cards = (state, action) => {
    switch (action.type){
        case 'ADD_CARD':
            let newCard = Object.assign({}, action.data, {
                score: 1,
                id: +new Date
            });
        //splitting the state object into individual properties
            return state.concat([newCard]);
        default:
            return state || [];
    }


};

//Redux helper function to pass reducer functions
const store = Redux.createStore(Redux.combineReducers({
    cards: cards
}));

//Keep an eye on the store for changes
store.subscribe(() => {
    console.log(store.getState());
});

//activate store action
store.dispatch({
    type: 'ADD_CARD',
    data: {
        front: 'front',
        back: 'back'
    }
});
I wasn't reutning an array at the default in cards instead I had {}. I guest I was returning an object ?


//Another action
store.dispatch({
    type: 'ADD_CARD',
    data: {}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
const cards = (state = [], action) => {
    switch (action.type){
        case 'ADD_CARD':
            let newCard = Object.assign({}, action.data, {
                score: 1,
                id: +new Date
            });
            //error is here
            return state.concat(newCard);
        default:
            return state || {};
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

State.Cards.Concat(newCard);
Your array is Cards not state.